# Origin and meaning of phrase "jede Menge"

Tags: etymology, phrase

The phrase "jede Menge" literally translated means "every amount" but it doesn't mean any amount but a large one.
Why does the phrase mean (almost) the opposite of the literal translation?

Comment: My [very first question here](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/58799/43989) was somewhat related. In general, hyperbolic expressions are not meant to taken literally or examined too closely in any language.

Answer (score 2):

What I will write it's not how linguistics works, but I also see your point of "why cannot *jede Menge* equally mean arbitrarily small quantities"?

For what is worth: In some hyperbolic (ling.) figure *jede Menge* is some kind of unboundedness: given some bound *L*, then *jede Menge X* means that for some criterion you are using to measure *X*, measuring *X* exceeds *L*.

So far you would have symmetry (*X*'s measure can be a lot smaller and OR lot larger than *L*), but *Menge* cannot shrink beyond nothing (smaller to the empty set you have nothing "emptier") as much as it can grow to infinity and this breaks the symmetry. Thus *Menge* means essentially large amounts.

For small amounts, you could use *jede noch so kleine...*

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly a generalization from the literal meaning *any amount*, indeed.

It works for example to say that the big man will pay any amount, which implies practically, for all intents and purposes, a hefty sum.

A more convoluted derivation requires a fossilized phrase with independent development of the individual components outside the phrase. In particular, the *je-* is cognate with *ewig* and Engl. *ever*, so origin from intensifier usage is theoretically imaginable, but I am not aware of such a meaning with the determiner *jede*. It would in this sense be similar to *so many* ~ *so manche*, which also shows a determiner (*so* was formerly in the article paradigm with articles, thus *Sie*~ *die* for example) and diverging meaning (*so manche* meaning "some" in practice).

By the way, in the obverse direction we also see *einiges* (cp. *any*) used to mean "much", too.

PS: I think it's also possible that the -d- was parasitic, intrusive because of words like *jederman, jederzeit*, etc. We also have *jemanden* (to somebody), thus *jemand* (somebody), and we certainly have what sounds to me like *je'e-Menge* in Mundart. Thus it's probably derived from any of the severly erroded senses of *je*, *ja*, *ganz, gar* (Mundart *janz*, *jar*)¹, etc. without -d-, which must then have become inserted later on. The augment is similar to *ever more*, where the *e-* is thought to be akin to *je-*, but the details are less than clear. A relation to Frankish, later French (*beaocup de* "a lot of") is also imaginable, cp. En. *all too many*, Ger. *allzuviele*.

1: *Der hat ja 'ne janze Menge ...* "he has a whole lotta ...". I'm thinkin it possible that *whole*, *holy shit*, *Heil ...  (long live ...), *heilen* (to heal, make whole) etc. belong here as well, cp. *aye* with a connotation pertaining to law, (potentially religios law) and *jeh* pertaining to longevity. See also *jedoch* ~ *although* (see [how to interpret the meaning of 'jedoch' in terms of 'je' and 'doch'?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29342/how-to-interpret-the-meaning-of-jedoch-in-terms-of-je-and-doch) NB: @imgonnamakeanaccounteventually is me). The etymologies of *whole, holy, heal*, Ger. *hold, Holz* and *all* are after all uncertain beyond Germanic, and the mere fact that eg. *allerdings* exists as well may be coincidence, an etymological doublette. *all* is thought to come from a sense "whole" (cf. Martin Haslelmath, 1995. Diachronic sources of ‘all’ and ‘every’)